# Gstreamer Sendonly WebRTC example work only locally?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, gstreamer

The  gstreamer WebRTC sendonly example works only locally. The examples are deployed on machine with a public IP address.
I am using gstreamer 1.20 on ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Furthermore, in the browser of the local machine where sendonly is deployed, when I use 127.0.0.1 the example works. However when I use the public IP of the machine, it does not work.

When it does not work, the sendonly program does not receive an SDP answer (soup_websocket_message_cb)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not using **https**. In order to use it with **http**, the browser should allow this. For example, you can do this in chromium based browsers, by enabling ***Insecure origins treated as secure*** in **chrome://flags/**. You should add your unsecured website there, for example "http://www.example.com"